# Does Sonar for Bamboo Add-on support Maven 2?

Tags: maven, sonarqube, bamboo, sonarqube-scan

I want to integrate Bamboo with SonarQube using [Sonar for Bamboo Add-on](https://mibexsoftware.atlassian.net/wiki/display/SONARBAMBOO/Sonar+for+Bamboo). According to [this](https://mibexsoftware.atlassian.net/wiki/display/SONARBAMBOO/Maven), Sonar for Bamboo Add-on supports Maven 2.

But it seems that SonarQube does not support Maven 2 according to [this](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONARQUBE51/Installing+and+Configuring+Maven). This documentation for SonarQube 5.1, but I did not find such page for SonarQube 5.3 and higher.

So My question is

- Does Sonar for Bamboo Add-on support Maven 2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sonar for Bamboo provides a [Maven 2 task](https://mibexsoftware.atlassian.net/wiki/display/SONARBAMBOO/Maven). But note that according to your link, Maven 2 is only supported up to SonarQube 4.5.

Cheers,
Michael